# A operator bivariate polynomial

Tags: operator-theory

Consider two bounded operators $S$ and $T$ on some Hilbert space, with $S$ nilpotent, $S^2 = 0$. Is there a formula for the polynomial $(S+T)^k$?

Or, a more special problem as follows:
consider the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = l^2(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R^2})$, consisting of square summable sequences with elements in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Embed $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathcal{H}$ by the zero coordinate:

$$
v \stackrel{\Phi}{\mapsto} (\cdots 0,v,0,\cdots).
$$

Let $S$ be a nilpotent $2 \times 2$ matrix, viewed as an operator on
$\Phi(\mathbb{R}^2)$, therefore $\mathcal{H}$. And let $T$ be the backward shift on $\mathcal{H}$. I would like to describe explicitly
the action of $(S + T)^k$ on $\Phi(\mathbb{R}^2) \subset \mathcal{H}$.

Comment: The best you could do is expand the product.  For instance,
$$
(S + T)^3 = \\
S^3 + S^2T + STS + ST^2 + TS^2 + TST + T^2S + T^3 =\\
STS + ST^2 + TST + T^2S + T^3
$$

Comment: $(T+S)^k=T^k+M$ where $M$ is the operator that maps $(...,a_{-1},\hat{a_0},a_1,...)$ to $(...,0,Sa_0,Sa_1,...,\hat{Sa_{k-1}},0,...)$, where the $\hat{}$ denotes the zeroth position and $Sa_i$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix being applied on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ element $a_i$.

Comment: @Bettybel Could you explain how you got that? Do you want to restrict $M$ to $\Phi(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

There are recursive formulas.  Let $(S+T)^k = S A_k + T B_k$.  Then
$A_1 = 1$, $B_1 = 1$, 
$$ \eqalign{A_{k+1} &= T B_k\cr
            B_{k+1} &= S A_k + T B_k\cr}$$